# Why aren't my ag-grid header excelStyles working?

Tags: javascript, excel, grid, export, ag-grid

I am trying to export my ag-grid as an Excel document. I added in excelStyles just for the header, but they aren't being applied to the document.

Here is the code:

```
  var columnWidth = 100;
  var params = {
    columnWidth,
    sheetName: 'Types',
    suppressTextAsCDATA: false,
    rowHeight: 25,
    headerRowHeight: 25,
    allColumns: true,
    excelStyles: [
      {
        id: 'header',
        font: {
          color: '#000000',
          bold: true
        },
        interior: {
          color: '#bed4f7',
          pattern: 'Solid'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  gridOptions.api.exportDataAsExcel(params);
}
```

What do I need to change to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who makes the same stupid mistake I did, you need to define the excelStyles in the gridOptions, not the params!